# Problem in R with xml parse output on the Window XP – breaking national symbol

Tags: r

I am interesting use R for data mining in the media research.

When I am pars xml (scraping Google RSS) national symbol (Cyrillic) is breaking:

```
>xml <- xmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)  
>xml  
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF‑8"?>  
<rss version="2.0">  
<channel>  
<generator>NFE/1.0</generator>  
<title>СЋРіСЂР° OR С…Р°РЅС‚С‹ OR С…РјР°Рѕ вЂ“ РќРѕРІРѕСЃС‚Рё Google</title>  
…
```

My system is:

> sessionInfo()
>       R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)

```
Platform: i386-pc‑mingw32/i386 (32-bit)  
locale:  
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251  
[3] LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C  
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251  

attached base packages:  
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base  

other attached packages:  
[1] XML_3.4-2.2 RCurl_1.6-10.1 bitops_1.0-4.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  
[1] tools_2.13.1
```

I am try used any custom options (`localeToCharset(locale="ru_RU.UTF-8")`) – without effect.

I've been running the parsing on the Linux (Lubuntu 11.04) – no problem, national symbol output correct.
Sorry for my English.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the exact URL, so I can try it?

Comment: Sure.  
Code for assembling url:  

    url.tmp <- "http://news.google.ru/news?hl=ru&gl=ru&q="  
    symbol <- enc2utf8("быть OR жить")  
    number <- 100  
    url <- paste(url.tmp, symbol, "&output=rss", "&start=", 1, "&num=", number, sep = "")  
    url <- URLencode(url)  

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the following worked for me, not sure if that is the case:

```
url.tmp <- "http://news.google.ru/news?hl=ru&gl=ru&q="
symbol <- "быть OR жить"
number <- 10
url <- paste(url.tmp, symbol, "&output=rss", "&start=", 1, "&num=", number, sep = "") 
url <- URLencode(url)
```

Basically, I've removed the `enc2utf8` from your example.

```
> xml <- xmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T, isURL=T)
> xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <generator>NFE/1.0</generator>
    <title>быть OR жить – Новости Google</title>
    <link>http://news.google.ru/news?gl=ru&amp;pz=1&amp;ned=ru_ru&amp;hl=ru&amp;num=10&amp;q=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+OR+%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C</link>
    <language>ru</language>
    <webMaster>news-feedback@google.com</webMaster>
    <copyright>&amp;copy;2011 Google</copyright>
    <pubDate>Wed, 21 Sep 2011 13:49:52 GMT+00:00</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 21 Sep 2011 13:49:52 GMT+00:00</lastBuildDate>
    <image>
      <title>быть OR жить – Новости Google</title>
      <url>http://www.gstatic.com/news/img/logo/ru_ru/news.gif</url>
      <link>http://news.google.ru/news?gl=ru&amp;pz=1&amp;ned=ru_ru&amp;hl=ru&amp;num=10&amp;q=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+OR+%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C</link>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title>Взяточникам будут давать до 50 лет тюрьмы - Дни.Ру</title>
      <link>http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGE1RZXvfqoSBuDU3EqSPeqJDRqDw&amp;url=http://www.dni.ru/redir/?source%3Ddni_picture_day%26id%3D219166%26dniurl%3Dpolit/2011/9/21/219166.html</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=http://www.dni.ru/redir/?source=dni_picture_day&amp;id=219166&amp;dniurl=polit/2011/9/21/219166.html</guid>
      <pubDate>Wed, 21 Sep 2011 12:54:00 GMT+00:00</pubDate>
```

I'm running R via the StatET plugin for Eclipse.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.4-2.2     quantmod_0.3-15 TTR_0.20-2      Defaults_1.1-1  xts_0.8-0       zoo_1.7-2       rj_0.5.5-4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.13.1     lattice_0.19-30 tools_2.13.1
```

Comment: If you receive different results, it might be due to the way you run R, and the console encoding it is using for the output.

Comment: I am unfortunate.   <code>    ...</item>
    <description>РќРѕРІРѕСЃС‚Рё Google</description>
  </channel>...
</code>

Comment: Yes. I am used RGui and RStudio.

Comment: And Rterm - is too incorrect output. You are right - message in the Rterm is unreadable. Where my bug?